# Tabbed content loads very slow

Tags: javascript, html, angular, performance

I've got an Angular application, where content is visible depending on selected tab. 
Tabs with small portion of html loads very fast, but in one tab I have 3 **select** elements and each one of them has approximetly 2 thousend avaiable options that comes from database.

When I click this tab, it takes few seconds until tab is displayed. Is there any workaround to speed up loading it?

```
<div *ngIf="tab=='Project'">
<select>

<option *ngFor="let item in employees>{{item.surname}}</option> 
</select>
<option *ngFor="let item in countries>{{item.shortCode}}</option> 
</select>
<option *ngFor="let item in positions>{{item.position}}</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** If you have three select elements with 2000 options each, that's 6000 nodes. It's simply taking a while to insert them into DOM. Think about why do you need 2000 options for the user and how does that help them in filling out the form. It's a nightmare to choose from 2000 options... three times!

Even if you use a different change detection strategy, loading them once is till going to take some time.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly right, but unfortunatelly there is no option to negotiate bussines requirments. Select lists are sorted descending and searching is fairly easy. But if could suggest them other approach, whout would you advice?

Comment: A search box. As you type, it displays suggestions based on what you type. It can all be done front-end, just don't include 6000 nodes at once for something that user won't even see.

Comment: I thought about this too, but wanted confirmation from someone else :)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you have `select` with huge amount of `option`s, then you should consider switch changed etection strategy to `onPush`

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component',
   ...
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush
});
```

Why? well if `zone` will wake up it will have to check every option if it's changed, for example `clicking` in select is waking up zone to check if something changed. However be aware of that if you switch to `onPush` then you might run into trouble with not refreshing UI due to that detect changes will be fired only on `events`, `xhr's` and changing in `@Input and @Output`, but you can always try to control it with importing `changeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()`. Also this [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) will be helpful to understand how it's work.

```
constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```